# Understanding For Loops

Tags: loops, for-loop

I'm trying out a for loop. I added an if statement to stop the loop once it reaches 30.
I have seen that `i <= 10` will run 11 times,  since the loop will still run when it reaches 10.

Why does the  code below run 11 times (first print line) if there is an if statement that sets `i` back to 0 when it reaches 10? Shouldn't it only print 10 asterisks instead of 11 - since it never reaches the 11th loop? Also, the second `if` sets `i` back to 10, which should let the loop run one more time, through the first `if`, which would and then set the `i` back to 0?

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{  
    Console.Write("*");
    if (i == 10)
    {
        j++;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        i = 0;
     }
     if (j == 30)
     {
         i = 10;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first loop, the line has 11 stars, because `i` iterates from 0 through 10, which is a total of 11 iterations.

Whenever `i` becomes the value 10, `j` is incremented, a newline is printed, and `i` becomes `0`.

However, when `i` is set to `0` within the loop, the loop makes `i` iterate from 1 to 10, for a total of 10 iterations.

This is because `i` is incremented just before the next iteration starts.

A `for` loop with this structure:

```
for (INIT; CONDITION; INCREMENT) {
    BODY
}
```

is more or less equivalent to this `while` loop:

```
INIT
while (CONDITION) {
    BODY
    INCREMENT
}
```

The caveat is when BODY has a `continue` statement, it actually jumps down to the `INCREMENT` part.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand why the lines only have 10 *  but i dont get the part that i is being incremented before the next iteration, at what point is that happening? i didnt add a 1++, etc. in the code.

Comment: @baztown: You did, in the INCREMENT part of your for loop: for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++). The INCREMENT executes right after the BODY executes (or right after a `continue`). See the comparison of `for` with `while` in my answer.