# For loop flow with a variable name as a condition.

Tags: c, for-loop

What does the following for loop do? When will the program break out of the loop?

```
for (c = 0; n; c++) {
  /* . . . */
}
```

Here is an example of such a for loop [in this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109036/1527084).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The loop will break when `n` becomes `0` (in other words, the loop will not stop until `n` becomes `0`). This can happen within the loop (the loop body sets `n` to `0` eventually), or it could possibly happen because of some external event. Examples of external events would be a shared memory update, or modification by a signal handler. The `c` variable is incremented as many times as the loop body is entered by the `for` loop. The `c` variable is initialized to `0`.

<sub><s>Technically, your code fragment is not a `for` loop, but just the controlling construct of a `for` loop statement. The fragment is missing a loop body. But that's okay, since your question title is about "this `for`-loop structure".</s> The question title and post has since been modified.</sub>

You link to a function in a different answer, but you already seem to understand that the purpose of that function is to count the number of set bits in a number.

Comment: @Veltas: There is only one part of the `for` controlling construct that has an `n` in it, only one part setting `c` to `0`, and only one part that increments `c`. So, I think I have that basically covered. However, if the asker or future answer seekers are interested, I have [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326857/315052) that explains the components of a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: This answer is an explanation of the bitwise operation in the linked question given in error.  It still explains the termination at the end.

The linked code is as follows:

```
long count_bits(long n) {     
  unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v
  for (c = 0; n; c++) 
    n &= n - 1; // clear the least significant bit set
  return c;
}
```

The interesting line here is `n &= n - 1;`. This sets `n` to `n & (n - 1)`, where `&` is the bitwise AND operator. The example says it clears the least significant bit, i.e. sets the lowest unit bit to 0, and that's exactly what it does, and here's why.

Imagine this example, we have the number, for example:

```
01010100
```

If we decrement (take 1), we get:

```
01010011
     ***
```

Every time we decrement the lowest bit is removed, and bits below become 1. That's just how subtraction works, it's the equivalent of 1000 - 1 = 999 in decimal, but with two digits instead of ten.

Now when we & them together:

```
 01010100
&01010011
=01010000
      ***
```

A bitwise & only sets a bit to 1 if both entered bits are 1.

So as you can see the operation always removes the lowest set bit as the lowest bit becomes 0 after subtraction, and the bits below were 0 before subtraction: all these bits fail to have both digits 1 for the & operation, and so evaluate to 0. All other set bits are unchanged, so give two 1s for the operation and keep their value.

The loop terminates when condition `n` is false, i.e. when `n` is `0` (all the bits are removed, value `00000000`). So this is after each bit is removed, and `c` leaves with value of the number of bits that were in `n`.

Remember that in C a boolean value is considered 'true' when the number form is non-zero, and 'false' when the number is zero.

Comment: Nice explenation! I can't understand that upvoters of an answer which doesn't even refer to the question...

Comment: Unfortunately the question wasn't phrased well, it's unclear whether or not they don't understand how a for loop works or they don't understand how the bitwise operations work in the linked post.

Comment: @Zaibis I only linked to that answer because I wasn't sure how the for loop will terminate. It wasn't about bit arithmetic at all.

Comment: @Geek well but then you should have specified your question more accurate, because it wasn't sure, what you wanted to know exactly.

Comment: @Zaibis sorry if you got confused by my question But I thought it is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard specifies that the "middle thing" in a `for` clause is an *expression*. As long as that expression evaluates to non-zero the loop is continued. So `n` is an expression that will lead to the loop being terminated once `n` is zero. A more explicit form would be

```
for (c = 0; n != 0; c++)
```

which any decent compiler compiles to the same code.

In fact, the C standard allows as a special case, the "middle thing" to be empty, in which case it is considered to be *true*. This is the reason why we can write infinite loops as

```
for (;;) { ... }
```

instead of the ugly as hell abomination `while(1)`.

Comment: I would argue that `while(1)` is more readable as it doesn't depend on C standard special case.

Comment: I'm with Jens on this one. `while(1)` is unbelievably ugly. And it's also more characters than `for(;;)` - having said which this is one of those cases where special macros like FOREVER could conceivably be justified.

Comment: `while(1)` is an abomination because 1) every C programmer *must* know `for(;;)` and 2) `while(1)` contains a constant value boolean that many lints warn about. There's no excuse for knowing your language well. I've seen even more people ask about ++i vs i++, so what?

Comment: Arguably `for(;;)` is obvious: surely it must loop indefinitely, after all what is the point of writing it?

Comment: A good programmer of course handles both `for(;;)` and `while(1)`. I just think that latter is more natural to read. However, I don't think that there is anything gained from wrapping this into macro.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words it is equivalent to `for( c = 0; n != 0; c++)`

Answer (score 0):

Heh..

[Case 1] - no loop's iterations

```
int c, n = &c;
for (c = 0; n; c++) {
  /* . . . */
}
```

[Case 2] - no loop's iterations

```
int c, n = 0;
for (c = 0; n; c++) {
  /* . . . */
}
```

[Case 3] - infinity loop's iterations

```
int c, n = ...; // any value, except 0
for (c = 0; n; c++) {
  /* . . . */
}
```

Is there another cases?

ps. of course, it's joke..